# Storing data in Thread Local Storage / HttpContext Current Items

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest, thread-local-storage

Storing data in Thread-Local Storage or `HttpContext.Current.Items`, which one is more efficient….?
This is for storing master data/parameters in a web application. 
Code for placing data in both method are: 
**1. System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items**

```
public static void Add(string pName, object pValue)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(pName, pValue);
}
```

**2. TLS**

```
public static void Add(string pName, object pValue)
{
    Thread.SetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot(pName), pValue);
}
```

Thanks....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are considering thread safety, go with Thread-Local Storage. If thread safety not required, then HttpContext.Current option is useful.